# how to read installed fonts in android

Tags: java, android

how to read installed fonts in android I am using code in this way
[image]

Comment: Please copy-paste your code. No screenshots.

Comment: Also, what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first error **getAssets**() you need to use context , passed it in Activity where you create your `Adapter` and in your `getView` do this `context.getAssets()` .For second error **txtDesc** you need get this variable with `holder` like this

```
holder.txtDesc.setTypeFace(font1);
holder.txtDesc.setTextSize(40.f);
```

Hope to help!

Answer (score 1):

u need to pass context of activity in adapter constructor and try this

```
context.getAssets()
```

Comment: txtDesc.setTypeface(font1);
        txtDesc.setTextSize(40.f);

Comment: holder.txtDesc.setTypeface(font1); holder.txtDesc.setTextSize(40.f);